# Message 'The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1'

Tags: python, twitter, arduino

This is my [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) code that does not work anymore. I get this message: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1".

The Python code basically uses the Python-Twitter library to ask [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) for the status of user "x", and it then takes the last status and searches for the term "#driptwit".
If found, it sends the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value of 1 to the serial port (and to the [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino)). If #driptwitstop is found, it sends an ASCII value of 0. Lastly, it loops and checks the Twitter account every 15 seconds looking for changes.

As you can see, below is where you enter the keys you got from Twitter in the last step.

What should I need to change in the code to fix it?

Here is the actual code:

```
Enter code here

##Import Libraries``

import twitter
import serial
import time

##Authenticate yourself with Twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumerkeyhere', consumer_secret='consumersecrethere', access_token_key='accesskey', access_token_secret='accesssecret')

##Set to your serial port
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 19200)

## Check serial port
def checkokay():
    ser.flushInput()
    time.sleep(3)
    line = ser.readline()
    time.sleep(3)

    if line == ' ':
        line = ser.readline()
        print 'here'

    ## Welcome message
    print 'Welcome To Drip Twit!'
    print 'Making Coffee..'

def driptwit():
    status = [ ]
    x = 0

    status = api.GetUserTimeline('X') ##Grab latest statuses

    checkIt = [s.text for s in status] ##Put status in an array

    drip = checkIt[0].split() ##Split first tweet into words

    ## Check for match and write to serial if match
    if drip[0] == '#driptwit':
        print 'Tweet received, making coffee'
        ser.write('1')
    elif drip[0] == '#driptwitstop': ##Break if done
        ser.write('0')
        print 'Stopped, awaiting instructions.'
    else:
        ser.write('0')
        print 'Awaiting tweet'

while 1:
    driptwit() ## Call driptwit function
    time.sleep(15) ## Sleep for 15 seconds to avoid rate limiting.
```

Comment: You need to change the source code/file that gets called by the "import twitter" line.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713230/authentication-for-new-twitter-api-1-1

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply
DOK I did not understand what should I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter API that your Twitter module is based off of has been discontinued. You'll need to refer to an updated Twitter package that'll use the 1.1 API instead.

Like @Madbreaks said: You might be able to write your own with some of the solutions presented in Stack Overflow question *[Authentication for new Twitter API 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762168/541208)*.

You'll have to write your own API using their 1.1 or find another package that supports 1.1 already. The important part of the error message is: `u'The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.'`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\project\arduino project", line 53, in <module>
    driptwit() ## call driptwit function
  File "C:\Python27\project\arduino project", line 32, in driptwit
    status = api.GetUserTimeline('x') ##grab latest statuses
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twitter.py", line 2721, in GetUserTimeline
    data = self._ParseAndCheckTwitter(json)

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twitter.py", line 3869, in _ParseAndCheckTwitter
    self._CheckForTwitterError(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twitter.py", line 3894, in _CheckForTwitterError
    raise TwitterError(data['errors'])
TwitterError: [{u'message': u'The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.', u'code': 68}]        **this is the output i get what sould i do?   i am not familiar whit python**

Comment: @Avi You'll have to write your own API using their 1.1 or find another package that supports 1.1 already. The important part of the error message is: `u'The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.'`

Comment: @Avi No problem at all. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Message 'The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1'

https://api.twitter.com/1/ change this to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/

Change both to 1.1
twitter/twitteroauth.php:

application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Twitter.php:

Comment: Simple, yet effective!

Comment: @imben Please paste full url for getting feed from specific channel
thanks