# How to login into facebook and twitter from link in php?

Tags: php, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, facebook-login

i have my username and password for facebook and twitter and i want to login facebook and twitter from my php page by providing username and password in anchor tag. how to do that?

```
    a href="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&email=abc@yahoo.com&pass=abc">Facebook /a>
    a href="https://twitter.com/login/?username=abc@yahoo.com&password=abc">Twitter /a>
```

Comment: Never, ever, EVER do this. You do not want your log (and possibly, some other logs?) containing an URL that includes your password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Facebook, there are several ways to create a Login easily. Of course you can use OAuth directly, but i would not recommended it:

- PHP SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk (See "Usage")
- JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
- Login Button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

General info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

For Twitter, this thread may help you: [Authentication for new Twitter API 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713230/authentication-for-new-twitter-api-1-1)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong. You should never pass password in query string.

Instead, to achieve Single Sign On (SSO) with Facebook or Twitter, You should use [OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/). Both Twitter and Facebook (and several others, such as google, Linkedin etc.) support [OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/)